# Second fragment in ViewPager consumes scroll events

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` that hosts `ViewPager` in my Activity. 
I am adding two fragments to the ViewPager. The first fragment has `RecyclerView` and the second fragment has a `ScrollView`.

On the first fragment, `SwipeRefreshLayout` was consuming scroll event. I added `OnScrollListener` and I am disabling refreshing if the view is not on the top.

I have same the problem with `ScrollView` in the second fragment, and I added `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener()` to `ScrollView`.

However, when I am on the first page, the scroll event passes to second page.

I tried to set `android:clickable="true"` on parent view of the first fragment and it didn't work.

Any recommendation would be helpful.

**my_activity.xml**

```
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/login_background"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/last_update"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/normal_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/caption"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_below="@id/last_update"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**first_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="16dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:clickable="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**second_fragment.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

There are some child views here. 

</ScrollView
```

**SecondFragment**

```
    onScrollChangedListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

            int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
            if (scrollY == 0) swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            else swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

        }
    };

    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);
```

Comment: Put `SwipeRefreshLayout` to `first_fragment.xml`.

Comment: Post the code how you set the `OnScrollChangedListener` . I think i know the problem

Comment: I added it as SecondFragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the second Fragment is created along with the first Fragment and it gains focus. I had this issue when I had used a Depth Page Transformer. The second Fragment was rendered under the first Fragment and was thus consuming touches.

Try using the following Page Transformer:

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new CustomViewPager.PageTransformer() {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        int pageHeight=view.getHeight();
        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        } 
        else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]

         float scaleFactor = Math.max(min_scale, 1 -Math.abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0) {
                view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
            } else {
                view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

            // Fade the page relative to its size.
            view.setAlpha((float) (0.2 +
                    (scaleFactor - min_scale) /
                    (1 - min_scale) * (1 - 0.2)));

        }
        else { 
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }       
});
```

The second Fragment is now rendered way off to the right and thus the touch events are passed to the first Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add separate `SwipeRefreshLayout` instead of declaring commonly,  for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="16dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:clickable="true">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/login_background"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we `add` the fragment instead of `replace`, the `fragment` underneath can consume the click/touch events in case the `fragment` on top is not consuming it. To avoid that, we can set the `root view` of the top `fragment` clickable as shown below (not in XML):

```
private var binding: FragmentFragment1Binding? = null

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentFragment1Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding?.root?.isClickable = true 
        return binding?.root
    }
```